# How to identify "similar" records without join

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have very big table in HIVE ,
sample data looks like this :

[image]

I want to identify and remove duplicate records :

if the fields 
'StudentID',
'courseID'
**are** identical and 'place' is **Not** the same , but **within 5 seconds difference**  in the 'date' field

for this example only the first (or second) row meets the critiria to be removed
so  I want to do a query which returns all other rows (=drop one of the rows no. 1 , 2  ),
**without** self join because the table is very big

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions.  Something like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(place) over (partition by studentid, courseid order by date) as next_place,
             lead(date) over (partition by studentid, courseid order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where unix_timestamp(next_date) <= unix_timestamp(date) + 5 and
      next_place <> place;
```

Comment: I added some rows to show that some rows won't pass the query.   rows no.  11,12 return but one of them should be removed

Comment: one of each couple (9,10) (11,12) (13,14) should be removed